# get request token google+ oauth 2.0

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am trying to login to my android app via google+. My code

```
OAuthService authService = new ServiceBuilder().provider(GoogleApi.class).apiKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY)
                .apiSecret(GOOGLE_API_KEY_SECRET).scope(GOOGLE_OAUTH_WEB_SCOPE)
                .callback(OAUTH_INTENT_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_GOOGLE_INTENT_HOST).build();

authService.getRequestToken();
```

But I receive next error `org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Consumer is not registered:`

Where can I get correct api key and api key secret? When I click `Create New Client Id -> Installed-> Android` developer console give me only client id. Where can i get secret key

Comment: when you create a new client id you should get the secret to go along with it: https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0

Comment: How can i get secret? I choose android application, fill all blanks but console give me only client id.